# Flutter photo edit apply adjustments

Tags: flutter, edit, photo, adjustment

Hello there can anyone please tell me how can i apply
**Exposure,
Brilliance,
Highlights,
Shadows,
Contrast,
Brightness,
Saturation,
Vibrance,
Warmth,
Color Tint,
Sharpness,
Blur,**

above all adjustments to image using flutter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without example code, it's difficult to give a specific answer.

You'll likely need to use a combination of [`ColorFilter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter-class.html) and [`ImageFilter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter-class.html) from `dart:ui`, there is a package on pub.dev called [`photofilters`](https://pub.dev/packages/photofilters) that may be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but for color filter i need color matrix and i don't know color matrix for all of them can you please i am searching it from 1 week and no luck it'll be very helpful if you find color matrix.

Thanks